# For every environment variable, create an environment variable with the base64 encoded value

Tags: sh, posix

For certain environment variables (`*_PASSWORD`), I want to create a second environment variable containing a base64 encoded copy of that variable (`*PASSWORD_B64`). I have a working solution for bash, but I would like to have a solution based on POSIX, so it runs in `sh`.

```bash
while read -r line; do
  CMD="${line}_B64=$(echo -n "${!line}" | base64)";
  export "$CMD";
done <<< $(env | grep -E "PASSWORD=" | sed 's/=.*//g')
```

I think there are two issues here:

1. Indirect parameter expansion `${!line}`: Which I could replace with `eval`.
2. The while loop with `<<<`: this was the only while loop I could get it to work with, since the other ways, it would run it in a subshell and the environment variables wouldn't be visible in the "parent shell".

Is there a way to get it to run in `sh`?

Edit: Here's an example of what the command above is doing:

```bash
$ env
TEST1_PASSWORD=Hello
TEST2_PASSWORD=World
$ # run command from above
$ env
TEST1_PASSWORD=Hello
TEST2_PASSWORD=World
TEST1_PASSWORD_B64=SGVsbG8=
TEST2_PASSWORD_B64=V29ybGQ=
```

Comment: where is your variable initially stored and where you want in final result?

Comment: They are environment variables in the shell where I call this command and should be available in the same shell afterwards. Maybe for better understanding: this is called in an alpine Docker container running /bin/sh.

Comment: `while read -r line; do eval "export ${line}_B64=\$(echo -n \$$line | base64)"; done < <(env | grep -E "PASSWORD="
| sed 's/=.*//g')` works at least in the ash shell variant in Alpine, although with the process substitution it's still not posix conform.

Comment: note base64 is not posix . https://github.com/JaHIY/shell-base64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, in POSIX, you jump straight into POSIX awk. Your code requires base64 to be installed.

The following runs an awk shell that filters the env and calls shell with base64 to output base64 encoded variable. The awk script outputs a `export var_B64=base64_of_var` for each environment variable. The result is then evaluated.

Also, at least GNU implementation of base64 from coreutils, splits long lines. Use `base64 -w0`.

```
export BLA_PASSWORD='hello * world'
eval "$(awk 'BEGIN{
  for (i in ENVIRON) {
    if (i ~ /^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*PASSWORD$/) {
      printf "export " i "_B64=";
      system("echo \"$"i"\" | base64 -w0");
      print;
    }
  }
}' /dev/null)"
echo "$BLA_PASSWORD_B64"
```

If you want it to be truly posix, write the base64 in awk.

Comment: And I thought it would be considered bad practice using awk/system. Good to know that it's common practice in POSIX! And also thanks for the hint with `base64 -w0`!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work...

```
#!/bin/sh
for line in `set`; do
        k=`echo $line|cut -d"=" -f1`;
        v=`echo $line|cut -d"=" -f2`;
        t=`echo $k|grep PASSWORD$`;
        if [ $t ]; then
                export ${k}_B64=`echo $v|base64`;
                echo export ${k}_B64=`echo $v|base64`;
        fi;
done
```

Comment: Check your scripts with shellcheck and implement suggestions. There are several problems.

Comment: `set | while ...` runs in a subshell, so the assignments and exports will be forgotten after `done`

Comment: that was the problem, yeah... it's working now

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks for pointing me to shellcheck. however, I find legacy backsticks very readable and user friendly. I know $() notation, but I prefer the ticks. For the other suggestion, well, for production-quality I can be reached, I have my fees, you know... ;-)